# IntelliJ Exe build not working as I expected

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, javafx

I am working on a JavaFX Application, which is a conferencing application. The application is running fine with IDEA. But my target is to build an exe from my application which would run standalone. I have configured an Artifact to build exe where I set the values for

1. Application Class
2. Title
3. Vendor
4. Version
5. Native Bundle (exe)
6. Enable Signing with Self Signed Key.
7. Build Output Level (Default).

With this, I can successfully build the exe file. When I install this exe, it doesn't run. My application has some dependency on other java libraries, which I have included in Output Root as Extracted. I have found that,

1. When I run the installed application it simply does nothing and simply exits without error. I haver tried to the run exe from cmd as well, but same here.
2. When I try to run the jar file of my application it it runs successfully.

though I have added these two lines in the MANIFEST file I am using,
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: sample.Main

I have tried
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/3231012?page=1
and many other solutions from internet. But nothing helped me in my case.

How can I debug this exe file or my project to successfully build an exe?

Comment: What version of JDK are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you guys. I have solved the problem.

My problem was, I was using

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    //some code here
});
```

Before `launch(args);` was called in the main Method. Which is fine if I run the program from IDEA (In my case it was IntelliJ) or if I run the program using `java -jar MyJar.jar` from command prompt. But it doesn't work when I run it from exe (An exception occurs in this case

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:273)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.runLater(PlatformImpl.java:268)
at javafx.application.Platform.runLater(Platform.java:83)
```

).

**How To Debug**

I had to put my whole code of main method inside a try catch block, and had to write the exception in a file or print the exception in the console.

**Solution**

If I put `PlatformImpl.startup(() -> {});` and change my code to

```
PlatformImpl.startup(() -> {});
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    //some code here
});
```

then it works.

thanks to

https://staticfinal.blog/2015/04/04/javafx-toolkit-not-initialized-solved/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of routes to export Javafx. I am assuming that you are exporting the file into a jar file first and compile it into an executable file.

1. The easiest way is to set JDK 8 on your project: File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK, because Oracle has removed Javafx from its compiler in the more recent versions of JDK. You can download JDK 8 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html). If you choose to use JDK 8, make sure that on your IntellijIdea exporting page you export it as a Jar file, not a Javafx file.
2. Use Gradle to build your Jar. Gradle will help you automatically manage your dependencies, and I think it's quite easy to set up in IntellijIdea - you can set it on the page where you initiate your project.

Regarding actually compiling it into a exe, I think [this](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle) StackOverflow post would be quite useful(you might have already come across this post).

Exporting java projects is definitely quite cumbersome. Good luck!